# Can you update invisible columns

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I'm trying to update the `row_start` column on a table with Versioning set. The row_start column is invisible.

```sql
UPDATE pgwebp.t_prov a
INNER JOIN pgwebp.t_prov b ON a.prov_id_a = b.prov_id 
SET a.row_start = b.system_ts_start;
```

Error message:

```
Unknown column 'a.row_start' in 'field list'
```

Comment: Please provide the table definitions of the tables in question so that it can be better understand what is happening. Just giving an update statement doesn't provide enough information.

Comment: Seconding what @JoeW said. There are [no issues updating an invisible column](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=b1401ef5b2750ed5233e579842f180f1) in general. More details are needed to understand what's going on.

Comment: Table has been set to versioning which creates the row_start and row_end columns. A simple update to these two columns throws the error Unknown column 'a.row_start' in 'field list';  Maybe a better question is can these columns which support versioning, be updated?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the bug/feature request [MDEV-16546](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-16546).

This pertains to the [system versioned tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/system-versioned-tables/) columns like `row_start` explicitly as normal invisible columns are currently still updateable.